# How to add dynamically name to input field?

Tags: angular

I need to use input field witch unique name for all fields. I cant't use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`, because I have validation problem in the form (these fields are ignored in validation). This is part of my code:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="rowgroupfooter" let-vehicle>
    <td>
      <mat-input-container class="full-width" color="warn">
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="vehicle.subscription_price" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required [disabled]="viewMode" type="number" min="0" [ngClass]="{ 'edited-price': vehicle.isSubscriptionPriceChanged }"
          (input)="vehicle.isSubscriptionPriceChanged=true;" pInputText appendTo="body" style="background-color: white">
        <mat-error>To pole jest wymagane</mat-error>
      </mat-input-container>
    </td>
...(more rows)
</ng-template>
```

So, how to add `name="index"` dynamically.

**E.g**

> name='1'
>
> name = '2'
>
> ...
>
> name = 'n'

Comment: Have a look at Angulars reactive forms. There is a FormArray which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use multiple inputs in form you can use form array here:

[reactive form array](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-importing-the-formarray-class)

[Basic Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array)

Create controls:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

 createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      people: this.fb.array([this.createArray()])
    })
  }

  createArray() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: null,
      addresses: null
    });
  }
```

Access Controls:

```
{{myForm.controls.people.controls[i].controls.name.value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms), so you can benefit of `FormArray`:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

so you can easily do things like:

```
<div formArrayName="yourFormArray">

  <div *ngFor="let control of yourFormArray.controls; let i=index">
    <!-- The repeated template -->
    <label>
      Your Control:
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so I guess in your Component's Class you will retrieve somehow the data from the server and according to that, you generate the controls of the FormArray

Comment: I should better specify my question, because client can add in any time new row with inputs, so I don't know how many rows i will have. (It was mistake before)